# How do I PUT a file with Typheous?

Tags: ruby, curl, put, typhoeus

I am trying to send a file via a `HTTP PUT` request. `Curl` allows this like:

```
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#PUT
```

What's the correct way of doing this with Typheous?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutriedsofar.com)

Comment: Tried: 
response = Typhoeus.put(some_url, params: a_hash, body: { file: File.open(file_to_upload, "rb") })
The body of the PUT ends up not being the content of the file.

Comment: This should go in your question.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW this is what I think was the complete (but not necessarily shortest) answer to the question.

Curl allows the uploading of files w/ PUT; the invocation is:

```
$ curl --upload-file filename url
```

where url may be something like:

```
http://someurl/script.php?var=value&anothervar=val&...
```

Typhoeus provides the same functionality, but the right way to pass url, params and their values as well as the file body is buried in the ethon docs:

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
    url, :method => :put, :params => params_hash,
    :body => File.open(filename) { |io| io.read })
```

Use request object to get response, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't have looked very hard:

> Examples:
>
> Make put request.
>
> ```
>    Typhoeus.put("www.example.com")
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> base_url (String) — The url to request.
> options (options) (defaults to: {}) — The options.
> ```
>
> Options Hash (options):
>
> ```
> :params (Hash) — Params hash which is attached to the base_url.
> :body (Hash) — Body hash which becomes a PUT request body.
> ```

http://rubydoc.info/github/typhoeus/typhoeus/Typhoeus/Request/Actions#put-instance_method

Comment: There is an example of how to POST files but not one on how to PUT. I expected the put method to take the same options like post, so I could pass in the file as a member of the :body hash, but that is not what I end up with.

Comment: You failed to mention any of that in your question. Perhaps telling us what you've tried, and why it didn't work, would help? Show sample code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You might also find the related post "[PUT vs POST in REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest?rq=1)" useful.

Comment: The problem is quite simple: send a file via PUT. Curl allows it as linked in the question. Using Typheous, via put, I end up with a PUT body that contains the stringification of my option hash, i.e., something like: ["filename", "application/octet-stream", "/path/to/filename"].

Comment: As I said, it should be mentioned in your question. Don't leave a trail of comments that slowly define your question's scope strewn through the answers. The better your question is asked, the faster we can help you find a solution. As is, you're going to make people trying to help you read every comment, and decipher the order they were posted, to figure out what you've done.